# $(window).scroll(function) is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to alert something whenever my window get scrolled but it's not working.
Here is my code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var ws = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(ws)
    {
        alert('Scrolled');
    }
});
```

Comment: It work, See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/j47nqrb4/)

Comment: it works just add <div style="height:1500px"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

CSS

```
body{
height:1200px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    alert('Hi');
});
```

(or)

```
  $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        var wstp = $(window).scrollTop();
       if(wstp)
      {
       alert('hi');
      }
    });
```

Just add height to your body tag and scroll.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this rule was to blame:

```
html,
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Hiding overflowing elements is fine as long as the rule is applied only to the body element.

Comment: You are my saver - thx for your answer!

Comment: For those, who like me are struggling with overflow troubles - I've used alternative API `scrollIntoView()` with pointing to a top-level element, which lets me keep my overflow settings

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine if you add an HTML element having height

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var ws = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(ws)
  {
        console.log(ws);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:1500px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute or initialize function, you have to write below simple code.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(scrollTop >= 10) {
     //here is your function name
   }
});
```